# How do I delete folders found in /opt/?

Tags: directory, delete, rm

I tried deleting a folder in my */opt/* file that I had created but got the message

```
rm: cannot remove '/opt/*': Is a directory
```

I created this folder, so why am I getting that message?

Thanks again for any help with this!

Comment: please post the command used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete a directory with `rm`, you need to add the `-d` option (if it is empty), or the `-r` option to delete recursively. Also you can use `rmdir` to delete empty directories. Check if you have inside some content you want to save to avoid accidental deletion.

Comment: `sudo` may also be required for deleting folder in  /opt

Comment: Thanks! Sudo rm -r deleted the folder and the contents of the folder.